# iOS Localizable Strings Word Count

Tags: ios, localization, translation, localizable.strings

I need to calculate the cost to translate an an iOS app. Prices are based on the number of words. I have everything I need to translate already in a Localizable.strings file.

Is there a tool or a command or something that I can use to tell me how many words there are in this file? This isn't going to be a matter of just pasting this into Word as I need to disregard all the keys and all of the comments.

Comment: Have you considered basic command-line tools like [`wc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/wc.1.html)?

Comment: That's not going to exclude comments and keys from my .string file, as far as I can tell .

Comment: Wouldn't know what your file looks like without a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bash script. Save into a text file (I named it `counter.sh`) in the same directory as your `en.lproj` folder.

```
# Delete the comments
cat en.lproj/Localizable.strings | sed '/^\\\*/ d' | sed '/^\/\/*/ d' > temp

# Delete everything up to and including the equals sign
cat temp | sed s/.*\=// > temp.1

# Delete the remaining quotes and semi-colon
cat temp.1 | sed s/\"// | sed s/\"// | sed s/\;// > temp.2

# Use wc to sount and spit out the number of words
wc -w < temp.2 

# Remove the temp files
rm -f temp
rm -f temp.1
rm -f temp.2
```

Open up that directory in Terminal.

Give the script executable permissions by running `chmod +x counter.sh`.

Run the script by typing `./counter.sh` and it should spit out the number of words in your `Localizable.strings` file.

Disclaimer! - My bash script skills are quite poor! This script will probably break if your strings contain escaped " or = chars, so it made need tightening up a bit. It's also horribly done, but should do what you need it to do!

Answer (score 1):

I ended writing a snippet in Swift, which I ran in a new OSX application, to count the words in the file.

```
let stringFileContents = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: "/path/to/file/Localizable.strings", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let stringsDictionary = stringFileContents.propertyListFromStringsFileFormat()

var words:[String] = []

stringsDictionary?.forEach({ (key, value) in
    words += value.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
})

// Ignore any word with % in it, since it's probably just a format substitution
let filteredWords = words.filter { $0.containsString("%") == false }

print(filteredWords.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like an update from the owners answer.

Put this piece of code on your current app and it will count the words by ignoring the variables, and also, without creating an array of words that causes lot of memory usage and time consumption too.

```
guard
            let stringFileContents = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings"),
            let stringsDictionary = try? NSDictionary(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: stringFileContents), error: ())
        else {
            print("Error happened :(")
            return
        }
        
        var words : Int = 0

        stringsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
            words += ((value as? String)?.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespaces) ?? []).filter({!$0.contains("%")}).count
        })

        print("Localizable.strings has \(words) words")
```